# Need to execute Query on Mysql DB every 5 sec in java

Tags: java, mysql, database

I need to execute below query on mysql DB once every 5 secs or 10 secs:

```
String query = "SELECT mins, HOUR, DAYOFMONTH, MONTH, DAYOFWEEK, path FROM cfg WHERE id=? AND isActive='Y'";
```

It's a small application & will have only 5 records in table.

Comment: its a small application & will have only 5 Records in table

Comment: you can edit you question, so don't have to comment to add sth.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I need to run a java program continuously, where requirement is from DB i need to query after a sleep say 60 sec & get details,suppose if i get from DB like 
(2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ) mins/hour/day of month/month/day of week - if current instant of time satisfies the DB fetched config then i need to execute something. please help me how can i implement this?